# Remove Bootstrap Styling of HTML Character

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

- A default *heavy check* (`&#10004;`) appears as "✔"
- Bootstrap 4.3 appears to be stylizing the check, forcing the browser to render as a thick-green one, which is undesired for my tastes -- refer to the example below
- I'd like to remove Bootstrap's styling, but cannot detect the styling rules that were used.  I've attempted to locate it via `grep -irn 10004` with no luck

How might I revert the styling back to the default to undo Bootstrap's work?

---

#### w/ Bootstrap:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

&#10004; 

<div class="small text-muted">
In case your browser is doing something different, this appears as a green checkmark in Bootstrap.  The green checkmark is not the default.  I don't know how to modify this HTML character so it shows with browser default styling.</div>
```

---

#### Default (Desired):

```css
.small.text-muted {
 color: #444;
 font-size: .85rem;
}
```

```html
&#10004; 

<div class="small text-muted">
This is how I want the checkmark to appear, but still including Boostrap on the page.</div>
```

Comment: You could strip it with JavaScript if you call this function (link) from <body onload=“htmlEntities(‘&#10004’)”> also doubt its from bootstrap https://gist.github.com/benjamincharity/9002211

Comment: Not sure what you're asking -- the Bootstrap version *does* display as a green checkmark.

Comment: @ObsidianAge The green check checkmark is not desired.  The default (as it appears in the StackOverflow post) is what is desired.  I'm uncertain how to revert it to default.  I cannot find the rule in Bootstrap files and browser devtools don't show any CSS markup.  I put the "should appear as green checkmark" thinking that your browser might apply different styling.  That might be confusing, so I'll edit

Comment: @bestinamir I still want a checkmark, I just want the natural dull-gray one that would show by default, not the thick-green one that Bootstrap has applied

Comment: @Mike can you replace with HTML elements like Font Awesome?

Comment: @vol7ron I'd like to avoid that.  The checkmark html character has unfortunately made it's way to different data layers and in different views. I am resistant to change it throughout the system and would prefer to stylize it one place in the front end, avoiding extra markup or having to replace via JS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason because the  "✔" check has style of green is caused of styled by the browser based on the font rule.

To be able to revert the styling back to the default style of check mark and undo the Bootstrap's CSS. You need to override the `font-family` property in the `body` and remove the `"Segoe UI Emoji"` font.

> Note that you need to add **!important** to override the style.

Please see the code below

```css
body{
  font-family: -apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,"Segoe UI",Roboto,"Helvetica Neue",Arial,"Noto Sans",sans-serif,"Apple Color Emoji","Segoe UI Symbol","Noto Color Emoji"!important
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

&#10004; 

<div class="small text-muted">
In case your browser is doing something different, this appears as a green checkmark in Bootstrap.  The green checkmark is not the default.  I don't know how to modify this HTML character so it shows with browser default styling.</div>
```

---

or In order to avoid using `!important` ( as [Jon P](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4665/jon-p) mentioned) you can create a `style` tag **after** the  inclusion of your bootstrap css file so that it will override the style.

> Note: Bootstrap css file should be declared **first** then declare the style to override next.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<style>
  body{
    font-family: -apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,"Segoe UI",Roboto,"Helvetica Neue",Arial,"Noto Sans",sans-serif,"Apple Color Emoji","Segoe UI Symbol","Noto Color Emoji"
  }
</style>


&#10004; 

<div class="small text-muted">
In case your browser is doing something different, this appears as a green checkmark in Bootstrap.  The green checkmark is not the default.  I don't know how to modify this HTML character so it shows with browser default styling.</div>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I was trying to do something similar to Mike, so I don’t want to speak for him, but in my case I cannot insert elements everywhere (in this case your span). So classes wouldn’t be a suitable solution. I’ll wait for him to chime in, though

Comment: @davecar21 I can confirm that the bold method works.  Now how can that be applied by default without using a CSS class as vol7ron describes or replacing all `&#10004;` with `&#10003;`?

Comment: @Mike understood, please see my updated code. hope it helps.

Comment: @vol7ron I have updated my answer and hope it works on your end.

Comment: Note that `!important` should be avoided when possible. You can avoid it in this case by making sure any css overrides for bootstrap are included **after** the inclusion of the bootstrap css file: https://jsfiddle.net/zsdc6ghw/

Comment: Thanks for the info @Jon P .. will update my answer

Comment: One last note, it doesn't need to be a `style` tag, it can be another css file, e.g *bootstrapOveride.css* that is included after the bootstrap file, but you've got the basics there.

Comment: I can't confirm that it works.  On OSX the checkmarks are black, but still appear stylized.  Though, I like your answer, which implies its not the style, but the font that was styling the special character.  This would explain many things.

Comment: I think vol7ron solved it.  It must be the font rule that has changed between versions of Bootstrap.  Thank you @davecar21 for all your help.  Could you modify your answer for it being styled by the browser based on the font and I'll select your answer?

Comment: Yes it is because of the font rule. @Mike Please see my updated answer. Glad to help.